# VS code auto tag completion selecting only closing tag

Tags: html, autocomplete, emmet

I'm new to vs Code. I like how when you type a tag in html it automatically adds the closing tag. But sometimes I don't want it because I will have something already written I want to add in between the tags.

For example, if I already wrote the code and I want to make it bold, I type the opening  tag, but then it closes it not surrounding the text.
Is there a way I can quickly jump to the end of that closing tag highlighting, or one key that I can hit which will delete that closing tag but leave the opening tag there?

image of how it starts off:

[image: img of how it starts off]

image of what I would like to do:

[image: img of what I would like to do]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [emmet](https://docs.emmet.io) to achieve your goal.

1. Frist, you select the word / text / paragraph you want to wrap.
2. Next you press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`, this lists you all commands available in VSCode.
3. Search for "Emmet: Wrap with abbreviation" (It's enough to just type emmet into the searchbox)
4. Now you can enter the HTML you want to wrap your selected text with by entering emmet syntax. If you want to wrap it with a tag, just write the tag, in your example this would be `b`
5. You can also wrap your text with multiple Tags and also add classes and attributes to these tags, for example: `a.more-link[title="test"][href="test.com"]` would wrap your text with `<a class="more-link" title="test" href="test.com"> ...your selected text ... </a>`

Comment: If this solves your problem please consider marking the answer as correct :-)